# Simplifying an function with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Given that variables $h_i, h_d $ are $\in \mathbb{C}$ i.e complex numbers.

Can the following be further simplified
$$h_dh_d,+h_ih_i+h_dh_d^*+h_ih_i^*\leq 2h_ih_d+h_ih_d^*+h_dh_i^*\tag 1$$

I know that (1) can be simplified into

$$h_dh_d,+h_ih_i+|h_d|^2+|h_i|^2\leq 2h_ih_d+h_ih_d^*+h_dh_i^*\tag 2$$

Any further tricks and properties of complex numbers to further simplify (2)?

Thanks

Comment: Wait, so you know in advance that both sides are real numbers?

Comment: yes thats corrct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original inequality is
$$
h_dh_d,+h_ih_i+h_dh^∗_d+h_ih^∗_i \leq 2h_ih_d+h_ih^∗_d+h_dh^∗_i
$$
In order for this inequality to make sense, both sides have to be real. Looking at the right hand side, we can recognise the last two terms as $2\Re (h_ih^*_d)$. This means that the first term on the right hand side is also real, as the difference between two real numbers is also real. We can therefore move $2h_ih_d$ to the left hand side.

On the left hand side, the last two terms are the magnitudes of complex numbers, exactly as you noticed, and these must also be real. We can therefore move them to the right hand side. Doing this yields
$$
h_dh_d,+h_ih_i - 2h_ih_d \leq h_ih^∗_d+h_dh^∗_i - h_dh^∗_d - h_ih^∗_i
$$
The left hand side can now be factored as $(h_d - h_i)^2$, while the right hand side also simplifies:
\begin{align*}
h_ih^∗_d+h_dh^∗_i - h_dh^∗_d - h_ih^∗_i &= -\left( h_dh^∗_d + h_ih^∗_i - h_ih^∗_d - h_dh^∗_i\right)\\
&= -\left( h_d - h_i\right)\left(h^∗_d - h^∗_i\right)\\
&= -\left\lvert h_d - h_i\right\rvert^2\\
&= - \left\lvert\left( h_d - h_i\right)^2\right\rvert\\
\end{align*}
The inequality then becomes
$$
 \left(h_d - h_i \right)^2 \leq - \left\lvert\left( h_d - h_i\right)^2\right\rvert
$$
If we let $\left(h_d - h_i \right)^2 = k$, for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$, we see that we have an inequality of the form $k \leq - |k|$, which can only be satisfied for $k \leq 0$. In terms of $h_i$ and $h_d$, this means that
$$
\left(h_d - h_i \right)^2 \leq 0,
$$
so the difference between $h_i$ and $h_d$ must be purely imaginary.